# Aparición de Div y Body no usable

Tags: html, css, modal

Estoy intentando hacer una pagina con un formulario q se muestre tipo modal, cuando el usuario quiera loguearse. Ademas quiero que cuando el modal se muestre, la pagina de atras quede con tono gris y que no se pueda usar mientras el modal este abierto.
De momento solo tengo un div q se muestra con un pequeño formulario.

Creen un html de ejemplo para que me ayuden, pero tiene lo mismo que el de mi pagina.

```js
 document.getElementById("btn_modal").onclick= function mostrarModal(){
    document.getElementById("modal").style.display = "block";
  }
```

```css
 #modal{
     display: none;
     border: solid 1px;
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
     margin-left: 25%;
     position: absolute;
     background-color: white;
   }

   #modal input{
     width: 80%;
   }

   #modal p{
     text-align: center;
   }

   body{
     background-color: rgb(242, 235, 235);
   }
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="btn_modal" type="button" name="button">Mostrar Modal</button>

  <div id="modal">
    <p>Bienvenido, ingrese usuario y contrase&ntilde;a</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Usuario"/>
    <br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Contrase&ntilde;a"/>
  </div>
  Este texto tiene que quedar en el fondo tapado por una capa gris.
  <br>
<br> 
  <button type="button" name="button">Este btn no se tiene que poder clickear si esta el modal abierto</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</body>
```

De momento no quiero usar ningun framework.

**PD:** Esta es una pregunta q vi hace un rato pero se cerro. Me parecio interesante, y quiero leer sus respuestas a ver como lo resolverian. Mas tarde publico la mia.

Comment: Mi respuesta era igual a la de @AlvaroMontoro, solo que para salir del modal, tenia q clickear en cualquier parte de la zona gris.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crea una capa entre el modal y la página de fondo (creo que puede llamarse scrim, aunque no estoy seguro, podría ser un elemento que contenga al modal para simplificar el asunto), que tenga posición fija y ocupe todo el ancho y alto de la ventana.

De ese modo no se podrá hacer ninguna operación sobre la página mientras el modal esté abierto. Cuando se muestre el modal, muestra esa capa. Cuando se cierre el modal, esconde la capa.

Algo como esto:

```js
document.getElementById("btn_modal").onclick = function mostrarModal() {
  document.getElementById("scrim").style.display = "block";
}

document.getElementById("cerrar_modal").onclick = function mostrarModal() {
  document.getElementById("scrim").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#scrim {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 990;
  display: none;
}

#modal {
  border: solid 1px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
}

#modal input {
  width: 80%;
}

#modal p {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(242, 235, 235);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="btn_modal" type="button" name="button">Mostrar Modal</button>
  <div id="scrim">
    <div id="modal">
      <p>Bienvenido, ingrese usuario y contrase&ntilde;a</p>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Usuario" />
      <br>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Contrase&ntilde;a" />
      <button id="cerrar_modal">Cerrar Modal</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  Este texto tiene que quedar en el fondo tapado por una capa gris.
  <br>
  <br>
  <button type="button" name="button">Este btn no se tiene que poder clickear si esta el modal abierto</button>
  <br>
  <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
  dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</body>
```